# Is there a way to make django i18n mark strings in the view as translateable and put it to the language file?

Tags: django, internationalization

In the django book by Holovaty he says, that django is not capable of translating strings marked with

urgettext('blahblah')

in the code and put it to the .po file with the "makemessage" command?

How do you solve to problem of having strings that should be translated?

Is there a way of getting this done: Making django detect the string within urgettext() in views and make it translatable with the .po file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was to import ugettext as an alias like

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as ut
```

django recognizes string when

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
```

is used...